Alternative between 2-step solvable or perfect
Recently I was thinking about $ SU(2) $ and noticed that every infinite closed subgroup $ H $ of $ SU(2) $ is either 2-step solvable
$$
[[H,H],[H,H]]=1
$$
or is perfect
$$
[H,H]=H
$$
Does anyone know of other groups that behave in this way (besides $ SO(3) $ since that is basically the same thing as $ SU(2) $)?
This property reminds me vaguely of the Tits alternative because the first option is that $ H $ behaves in a very solvable way while the second option is that $ H $ behaves in a very not solvable way.

Your statement about SU(2) is simply wrong; you probably meant Lie subgroups.

@MoisheKohan ah yes that's right let me add in the word closed

Here are two observations to help you to classify such Lie groups:

If $G$ is a noncompact connected semisimple Lie group, it contains a closed subgroup locally isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ and, hence, a discrete nonabelian free subgroup.

If $G$ is a compact connected semisimple Lie group of rank $\ge 2$ and $g\in G$ is a noncentral singular element, then the centralizer of $g$ in $G$ splits as a product of a nontrivial semisimple group and a nontrivial abelian group.
(A singular element of a compact connected Lie group is one which does not belong to a unique maximal torus.)


As a consequence of 1 and 2, if $G$ is a connected Lie group, $G=S\rtimes H$ is its Levi-Malcev decomposition (with solvable $S$ and semisimple $H$), and $G$ satisfies your property, then $H$ is either trivial or compact of rank 1, i.e. $H=SO(3)$ or $H=SU(2)$. From this, you should be able to complete a classification of groups $G$.
Edit. Unless I overlooked something, $G$ will be either (at most) 2-step solvable, or $SO(3)$ or $SU(2)$.

Ah ok so by your fact 2 it seems that only groups with rank one would have this property. So groups like $ SU(2), SO(3), SL(2,\mathbb{C}), PSL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ and I guess also $ SL(2,\mathbb{R}),PSL(2,\mathbb{R}) $ and the universal cover of $ SL(2,\mathbb{R}) $. Also perhaps this is a silly question but what does it mean for $ g \in G $ to be a singular element?
